# Can npm-update and npm-install give different result?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-update

Let's say we have 3 packages with the following dependencies:

**C** -> **B**@^1.0.0  and  **B** -> **A**@^1.0.0

(module **C** depends *only* on module **B** version 1.0.0 and above; module **B** depends on module **A** version 1.0.0 and above;)

Now I'm doing the following steps:

1. npm-install in module C (result: node_modules contains A@^1.0.0 and B@^1.0.0)
2. npm-publish of higher version of module A: A@^1.0.1
3. npm-update in module C (result: node_modules contains **A@^1.0.0** and B@^1.0.0) --- A module didn't changed!

But, if i'm cleaning node_modules and then npm-install module C again, i'm getting that node_modules contains **A@^1.0.1** and B@^1.0.0

- Is there any way i can get full updated node_modules without delete and install it again?
- If not, what is wrong in the way I manage the dependencies? I don't want  explicitly add all the dependencies trees so node-update will work

Answer (score 0):

`npm update` respects semantic versioning, it will not update major versions of packages if you have a `^` dependency.

`^` on a dependency literally means that it's only fine to update up to a minor version - since major versions contain breaking changes.

> This command will update all the packages listed to the latest version (specified by the tag config), respecting semver.

From [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)

Comment: we fixed the question accordingly. the focus here is that our sub dependencies aren't updated in the root applications (direct dependencies are)